# Azure Speech and Speaker Services in Teams Chatbot

Tags: c#, botframework, speech-recognition, chatbot, microsoft-teams

Below is my code basics planning for implementation in chat bot:

- develop teams core bot by enabling calling feature in teams channel settings.
- upload bot as custom app and enable for Private, team, group options in teams app settings.
- enable API graph permissions in bot channel  registration for group calling in
  teams.
- Azure Speech Service (speech recognition) speech  to text will implement in bot.
- Azure Speaker Recognition Service to know which
  user is speaking will implement in bot.

For Speech and Speaker services, I already tried sample POC in console.

**So  my queries:**

1. Is it possible to add my bot in group meeting/channel group? or vice versa is possible(Adding users to bot)?
2. If #1 is yes, say the group call is connected to all members along with bot, is it possible by using speech to text API from bot to convert whatever user speaks and display in chat automatically?
   Ex: 3 users joined in channel group , I added bot in that channel group  or consider vice versa like in the bot app I added 3 users.
   When 3 users are speaking in call, I want to convert speech to text and display in group chat using bot.

***Is this scenario possible for implementation in Teams?***

In short: just like live captions are displaying in teams audio chat pane, I want it to display same on chat panel.

Better understanding with example on Group audio call with bot in Teams:

```
     Ex:(speaking/spoke) User1: Hi Everyone
     (Displaying in chat panel) :Bot:  User1-Hi everyone

      (speaking/spoke) User2: Hello Everyone
      (Displaying in chat panel) : Bot: User2- Hello everyone
```

I already explored some part of this, but it happens in UWP and window forms. so not sure it can be possible in teams with extension messaging.

Reference Links:

- https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/tutorial-voice-enable-your-bot-speech-sdk
- https://bisser.io/bot-framework-teams-messaging-extensions-walkthrough/
- https://microsoftgraph.github.io/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/docs/articles/calls/register-calling-bot.html

Comment: Thank you for reaching out to us We will investigate and if we require further information we will reach out. Best regards, Teams Platform

Comment: Yes, it is possible to add a Bot in meeting chat but Bot cannot convert the speech from user into text messages.

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT, so if bot wants to reply something in call for any user, how bot understand what user speaks and reply accordingly?

Comment: I am checking this internally.

Comment: Having a bot understand what a user is saying requires the integration of a cognitive services API. To achieve that, a bot can use application hosted media to get a raw stream of media. Could you please take a look at the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communications-media).